# cURL post api call with authentification on Aliseeks api

Tags: php

I am trying to connect to the [Aliseeks api](https://docs.aliseeks.com/api/#introduction) with CURL but I am not sure where to put my api key.

On the API's doc they say

> "Aliseeks expects for the API key to be included in all API requests
>   in a header that look like the following: X-Api-Client-Id: Your Api
>   Key"

Now I am doing this :

```
$url = 'https://api.aliseeks.com/v1/products/details';
$curl = curl_init();
$auth_data = array(
    "X-Api-Client-Id" => 'my_api_key_here',
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, $auth_data );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $auth_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
curl_close($curl);
echo $result;
```

But in the return I get :

```
[{"code":"no_token_found","violation":"aliseeks.authentication.notokenfound"}]
```

Any idea ?

ps: the $auth_data is here twice because I am trying kind of everything now...

Comment: `CURLOPT_HEADER` specifies whether you want the _response_ headers included in the output. Sending request headers is done via `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`. (And you need to put header name and value into _one_ string in the array you pass to that, it is not an associative array.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a wrong constant to send the headers.

It should be `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` instead of `CURLOPT_HEADER`.